# Match strings starts and end with particular character in a String using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

Here is my string. The total json response comes as a String. Task is to identify the words after subdomain and comment.

{item_type:a,custom_domain:"google.com",subdomain:analytics,duration:324.33, id:2892928, comment:goahead,domain_verified:yes}, {item_type:b,custom_domain:"yahoo.com",subdomain:news,comment:awesome,domain_verified:no}, {item_type:c,custom_domain:"amazon.com",subdomain:aws,width:221,image_id:3233,height:13, comment:keep it up,domain_verified:no}, {item_type:d,custom_domain:"facebook.com",subdomain:m,slug:sure,domain_verified:yes}

The output should be like,

```
analytics, goahead
news, awesome
aws, keep it up
m, sure
```

To put it simply, I need words starting with ^subdomain: and ends with a comma and then words starting with ^comment: and ends with a comma.

The incoming string contains huge amount of data. Each and every string will contains thousands of subdomain and comments. I've tried with preg_match_all method. But I didn't get the proper way to do it.

Comment: can you show us what did you already done ?

Comment: i don't see `comment` in 4th JSON

Comment: Surely you've been a member long enough to realize that this is nor the way nor the type of question to ask here?

Comment: Yes. I shouldn't have put the question in a very vague manner. Do you want me to take down the question? But I got the answer that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 ways (I'm not sure about which one has the best perfs, but I will bet on the last procedural way):

1. Using the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) function, you will get an array from your string and then just iterate over it to get your data
2. Using regexp, see [an example here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fvz) with pattern `/subdomain:(.*?),.*?comment:(.*?),/`
3. Using a procedural function, like :

   ```
   $subdomains = [];
   $comments = [];

   $subdomainLen = strlen('subdomain:');
   $commentLen = strlen('comment:');

   $str = '{item_type:a,custom_domain:"google.com",subdomain:analytics,duration:324.33, id:2892928, comment:goahead,domain_verified:yes}, {item_type:b,custom_domain:"yahoo.com",subdomain:news,comment:awesome,domain_verified:no}, {item_type:c,custom_domain:"amazon.com",subdomain:aws,width:221,image_id:3233,height:13, comment:keep it up,domain_verified:no}, {item_type:d,custom_domain:"facebook.com",subdomain:m,slug:sure,domain_verified:yes}';

   // While we found the 'subdomain' pattern
   while(($subdomainPos = strpos($str, 'subdomain')))
   {
       // Removes all char that are behind 'subdomain'
       $str = substr($str, $subdomainPos + $subdomainLen);

       // Retrieves the subdomain str and push to array
       $subdomains[] = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ','));

       // If pattern 'comment' exists, do the same as before to extract the comment
       if($commentPos = strpos($str, 'comment'))
       {
           $str = substr($str, $commentPos + $commentLen);
           $comments[] = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ','));
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Giving you string example you can use the following regex, to capture all the subdomains:

```
/(subdomain:)[\w|\s]+,/gm
```

And:

```
/(comment:)[\w|\s]+,/gm
```

To capture comments.

Here's a [working example](http://regexr.com/3dao6) for subdomains.

If just want the content of the subdomain or comment you can then remove them from the match results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...  Here is [LIVE EXAMPLE](https://eval.in/561399)

```
<?php 
$string ='{item_type:a,custom_domain:"google.com",subdomain:analytics,duration:324.33, id:2892928, comment:goahead,domain_verified:yes}, {item_type:b,custom_domain:"yahoo.com",subdomain:news,comment:awesome,domain_verified:no}, {item_type:c,custom_domain:"amazon.com",subdomain:aws,width:221,image_id:3233,height:13, comment:keep it up,domain_verified:no}, {item_type:d,custom_domain:"facebook.com",subdomain:m,slug:sure,domain_verified:yes}';
$v1= explode(',',str_replace("}","",str_replace("{","",$string)));
$result =array();

foreach($v1 as $key=>$val)
{
    $v2 = explode(':',$val);
    if(trim($v2[0])=='subdomain' || trim($v2[0])=='comment')
    {
        $result[]= $v2[1];
    }
}
echo implode(',',$result);
?>
```

This will output :

```
analytics,goahead,news,awesome,aws,keep it up,m
```